# Average size of class groups of cyclotomic fields: three perspectives

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, iwasawa-theory

Let $K$ be a number field. Let $h(K)$ denote the class number (i.e., the size of the ideal class group) of $K$, $R(K)$ be the regulator of $K$, and $\Delta_K$ the discriminant of $K$.

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of number fields, and let $\mathcal{F}(X)$ be the elements in $K \in \mathcal{F}$ having absolute discriminant $|\Delta_K|$ bounded by $X$. By Hermite-Minkowski, $\mathcal{F}(X)$ is always a finite set.

If $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{F}_2^{\pm}$, the family of imaginary/real quadratic fields respectively, then the Gauss-Mertens-Siegel theorem states that

$$\displaystyle \text{ (1) } \sum_{K \in \mathcal{F}_2^{\pm}(X)} h(K) R(K) \sim c_{\pm} X^{3/2} ,$$

where $c_\pm$ are positive numbers. The Brauer-Siegel theorem states that if $\mathcal{F}$ is a reasonably nice family of number fields, then

$$\displaystyle \lim_{K \in \mathcal{F}} \frac{\log h(K) R(K)}{\log |\Delta_K|} = 1.$$

Here we are asking for a formula similar to (1), when $\mathcal{F}$ is one of the following three families:

$\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{K}$, the family of all cyclotomic fields ;

$\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{K^\prime}$, the family of cyclotomic fields $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$, where $\zeta_p$ is a primitive $p$-th root of unity, and $p$ runs over all primes;

$\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{K}_p$; the family of cyclotomic fields $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^n})$ where $p$ is a fixed odd prime, $\zeta_{p^n}$ a primitive $p^n$-th root of unity, and $n$ runs over all natural numbers.

Is (1) known for $\mathcal{K}, \mathcal{K}^\prime$, or $\mathcal{K}_p$ for any odd prime $p$? In other words, is the average size of $h(K) R(K)$ known for any of these three families of cyclotomic fields?

Comment: In these families the conductor grows very rapidly.  So I'm not sure that the averages buy you much.  For example in the family of fields ${\Bbb Q}(\zeta_p)$, the sum is probably dominated by the largest prime below $X$.  One might normalize by dividing by a suitable power of the conductor, so that you're asking about the average of the product of all $L$-values at $1$.  This also seems a bit delicate.  See Granville's papers on the first factor of cyclotomic fields, which deals with similar questions for the relative class number of cyclotomic fields wrt the maximal real subfield.